# C++ Function accessibility

Tags: c++, function

I have issues in my c++ programm.

I have 6 files:  main.cpp , Helper.h , Data_1.h ,Data_1.cpp, Data_2.h, Data_2.cpp

Here is the source code of each file:

main.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include "Data_1.h"
    #include "Data_2.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    Data_1 D1;
    Data_2 D2;

    D1.Print_Data_1();
    D2.Print_Data_2();

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Helper.h:

```
#ifndef HELPER_H_INCLUDED
#define HELPER_H_INCLUDE

struct My
{

 My(){};

void Func()
{
    printf("Helper\n");
}

~My(){};


};

#endif // HELPER_H_INCLUDED
```

Data_1.h:

```
#ifndef DATA_1_H_INCLUDED
#define DATA_1_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Helper.h"

class Data_1: public My
{

public:

Data_1();


void Print_Data_1();

~Data_1();




};
#endif // DATA_1_H_INCLUDED
```

Data_1.cpp:

```
#include "Data_1.h"


Data_1::Data_1():My()
{

}


void Data_1::Print_Data_1()
{
printf("Hello 1\n");
Func();


}

Data_1::~Data_1(){}
```

Data_2.h:

```
#ifndef DATA_2_H_INCLUDED
#define DATA_2_H_INCLUDED


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Helper.h"


class Data_2: public My
{

public:

Data_2();

void Print_Data_2();

~Data_2();



};

#endif // DATA_2_H_INCLUDED
```

Data_2.cpp:

```
#include "Data_2.h"

Data_2::Data_2():My()
{

}


void Data_2::Print_Data_2()
{
printf("Hello 2\n");

Func();
}

Data_2::~Data_2()
{

}
```

When i try to compile the code, it compiles  succesfully.

The output:

```
Hello 1
Helper
Hello 2
Helper
Hello world!
```

I decided  to remove the structure  "My" in Helper.h and only keep the function Func() i also  removed  the inheritance in Data_1.h and Data2_.h

This is Helper.h after removing the structure:

```
 #ifndef HELPER_H_INCLUDED
 #define HELPER_H_INCLUDED


void Func()
{
printf("Helper\n");
}

#endif // HELPER_H_INCLUDED
```

When i try to compile the entire code, it fails and the compiler tells me:

```
... Helper.h:10: multiple definition of `Func()' 
... Helper.h:10: first defined here
```

My code compiled successfully before removing the struct.

My Question: Why the code compiled successfully with the struct "My" and why the code failed to compile after
removing the struct

Can you help me please.

Comment: `Func()` inside `struct` is treated as inline while one outside `struct` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a function is defined in a header file, it must be declared `inline`. Otherwise its definition is copied in all the places, where you include that header file, hence why you get the "multiple definitions" error. Remember that including a header file in C++ basically means that the compiler copies the file's contents at the point of including.

Class methods defined inside the class' declaration are considered inline by the compiler.